# How to create Angular 2 list with additional element at the end

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating a grouped list using ngFor -  a list in a list.

At the end of the list I would like to add an extra element not part of the enumeration.

I have tried a few things but can't quite get it right, how should I do this using angular2?

Normally you would have this:

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="#item of myFirstArray">
    <ion-item-divider light>{{item.name}}</ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item *ngFor="#secondItem of item.mySecondArray; #i = index; #isLast = last">
         {{secondItem.name}} from {{item.name}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
```

This is what I tried:

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="#item of myFirstArray">
    <ion-item-divider light>{{item.name}}</ion-item-divider>
    <element *ngFor="#secondItem of item.mySecondArray; #i = index; #isLast = last">
        <ion-item>
             {{secondItem.name}} from {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngIf="isLast">
             Something else is here.
        </ion-item>
    </element>
</ion-item-group>
```

This works of course but I thought `element` was not supposed to be rendered as part of Angular2, but it is and it's messing up the stylesheet.

How should i do this correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the canonical form of `ngFor` with the explicit `<template>` tag

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="#item of myFirstArray">
    <ion-item-divider light>{{item.name}}</ion-item-divider>
    <template ngFor let-secondItem [ngForOf]="item.mySecondArray" let-i="index" let-isLast="last">
    <!-- old `#` syntax
        <template ngFor #secondItem [ngForOf]="item.mySecondArray" #i="index" #isLast="last">

    -->
        <ion-item>
             {{secondItem.name}} from {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngIf="isLast">
             Something else is here.
        </ion-item>
    </template>
</ion-item-group>
```

(assuming the new `ngFor` syntax with `let` instead of `#`)

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html